# Bananas have blue/green spots - Are these safe?

Tags: food-safety, food-science, bananas

In all my years of buying bananas, I have never seen this. In this case, the bananas are organic and sourced from Peru (no idea if that makes a difference or not).

I bought the bananas when they were still somewhat green. The spots were hidden in the green swaths of the banana peel, so not visible when I first purchased the fruit. Now that they are ripening, small blue/green (almost light turquoise) spots are becoming evident.

What is it? Is it dangerous to me, to my pets, and/or to my houseplants?

Note: I realize this is not strictly a cooking question. But of all the stackexchange sites, this seemed the most logical one for asking the question.

[image: Picture of banana with blue/green spots.]

Comment: Pictures please? That sounds like a challenging question? (For the record, that question is perfectly fine here.)

Comment: Picture was added.

Comment: That is such an interesting picture.  The green is so vivid.  I wonder if there was something up against the peel there such that it did not ripen with the rest of it?

Comment: It was a bunch of six bananas. All of the others also have the same spots.